# How to get variable from js file in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

Hi guys im trying to get a variable called ipAdress from server.js which is in folder 'server' into my React component called Container.
This is the server.js file with the variable

```
var ip = require("ip");

var ipAdress = ip.address();
console.log(ipAdress)
```

And in the container I imported it like this:

```
import ipAdress from '././server.js';
```

But it tells me it can't resolve it. Can someone tell me the correct way to do it. If necessary I have the github link here so you can take a look at the file structure: https://github.com/darja2001/collaborative-whiteboard-SR

Answer (score 0):

You have to export `ipAdress`

E.g.

```js
var ip = require("ip");

var ipAdress = ip.address();

export default ipAdress
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of default exports:
In your server.js file, you have to export the ipAdress

```
var ipAdress = ip.address();
export default ipAdress;
```

And wherever you want to import simply write,

```
import ipAdress from '././server';
```

In case of named exports:
In your server.js file,

```
export const ipAdress = ip.address();
```

And wherever you want to import,

```
import { ipAdress } from './serv';
```